# Open page at first login

Tags: python, django

I want that users must fill out a form after the first login. With the signals I've already tried:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

[...]

def umleiten(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    print reverse("first_login")
    """Check if a user logged on for the first time.""" 
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("first_login"))

user_logged_in.connect(umleiten)
```

The function "umleiten" is called but it will not be forwarded to the appropriate page.
Is there a way to call a function *after* the login from which I can forward to another site.

Comment: Please post code where u have mentioned url which will call while reversing first_login as well as first_login code also..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can and probably should use middleware for that

```
class FirstLoginCheckMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):

        is_form_page = request.path in (
            settings.FORM_PAGE
        )

        if (not is_form_page) and request.user.is_authenticated() and (not request.user.profile.filled_out_the_form):
            return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.FORM_PAGE)
        return None
```

Where, e.g. you've extended User with an object that has a BooleanField which gets checked once the user did what you've wanted them todo:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
     filled_out_the_form = field.BooleanField(default=False)
     # ...
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I must chance
    is_form_page = request.path in (settings.FORM_PAGE)
to
    is_form_page = settings.FIRST_LOGIN_FORM_PAGE in (request.path)